# phpMyAdmin and latin1_swedish_ci

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, collation

I create new database with utf8_general_ci collation, create test table also with utf8_general_ci collation, and then i click on my database(structure) and this is what i get:

[image]

Why is that "latin1_swedish_ci" showing up?

Edit:

Ok how to change this, it is in phpmyadmin in "Variables" tab, under "Server variables and settings":

[image]

This is how it looks like when i am creating new database:

[image]

Comment: if you wanna change your existing database try this: http://serversupportforum.de/forum/sql/9279-kollation-von-tabellen-aendern.html#post69306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually collation problems will cause your queries to run exceedingly slow, so it's important that everything is setup properly.

You have a database connection collation, a database collation and a table collation. Be sure all three are setup to utf8. If the problem persists, check your phpmyadmin configuration file and see what collation defaults are showing up.

Comment: If you look on the front page of phpMyAdmin, you'll notice that when you create a new database, it has a setting for "MySQL connection collation:". Be sure when you create a new database that both that and the database collation are set to utf8. It may be as simple as recreating a new database, copying your current one to the new one, then renaming it. (assuming your database is fairly small)

Comment: Dooltaz i updated my question, both of those are set on utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0):

goto phpMyAdmin's folder look for config.inc.php. Open it and search for 'collation', probably arnd line 370 - change it to -

```
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Comment: Hmm config.inc.php only have 26 lines and not one "collation"... :(